# "Cannot find namespace" in Promise type argument

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following code:

```
import bre from "@nomiclabs/buidler";

async function main(): Promise<bre.ethers.Contract> {
  const Greeter = await bre.ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
  // bre.ethers.Contract exists here
}
```

The issue is with the Promise return type. It doesn't compile:

[image: Cannot find namespace]

Why doesn't TypeScript compile it, if bre.ethers.Contract exists? If written inside the function, I can use it as a type.

Comment: `import { ethers } from "@nomiclabs/buidler";`
https://buidler.dev/guides/typescript.html

Comment: That's not the issue. Using ethers directly just changes the error to this: `Cannot find namespace 'ethers'.ts(2503)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a warning from the Typescript playground for the following:

```
interface T {
    A: {
        B: {
            test: string
        }
    }
}

var a = new Promise<T.A.B>((res, rej) => {
    res({test: "hello"});
});
```

> Cannot access 'T.A' because 'T' is a type, but not a namespace. Did you mean to retrieve the type of the property 'A' in 'T' with 'T["A"]'?

I did what It said and it appears to provide your desired outcome:

```
interface T {
    A: {
        B: {
            test: string
        }
    }
}

var a = new Promise<T["A"]["B"]>((res, rej) => {
    res({test: "hello"});
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrIN4Chm+QQQC5Mc8yAhY7MmvSAZzGMalAHNTaBfT5HnrADc4UZHGQBeZCAgB3ZAAUoAewC2wehAA8qANoAifPoC6B8iYB8ACitQI9ADTI7AKwCUkiyTJ36VjAxMyPoAFhAANuHK+lxuANxYsXFAA)

Comment: Someone may have a cleaner solution than this because referencing the properties as strings isn't the greatest solution if those property names were to change. Probably fine in this case though as those properties are coming from a 3rd party library (by the looks)

Comment: Interesting. The ["A"]["B"] doesn't work in my case, because `bre` is not an interface, but I still accepted the answer because it clarified why TypeScript doesn't compile the damn thing. It's because of [TS2713](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.9.3/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json#L2658).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Welp, win some lose some I guess haha